# I-V curve of resistor in special condition

Tags: resistors

What will happen to the i-v curve of a resistor when we apply more power than its nominal power? for example applying 30v to 100ohm resistor which nominal power is 0.5w.

Comment: In your example, you're putting 9W through a 0.5W resistor,  It will heat up and burn and go open circuit quickly, possibly with a brief flash.that could be harmful.

Comment: Not necessarily open circuit failure. You can also get shorts when stressing resistors to much.

Comment: If the resistor survives, the i-v curve will no longer be linear as temperature will not be constant. The resistance value will increase because of increase in temperature and the `i-v` curve will bend toward `i` axis.

Comment: You could apply it for less than a millisecond and it might still be good.

Comment: @beccaboo what about carbon film resistors? their value decrease in temperature rise. the curve will bend toward v or not?

Comment: Ofcourse negative temperature coefficient will bend toward v. You got it right!

Comment: @beccaboo Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I model resistors based on their physical size, assuming the core of the resistor is pure silicon.

As I computed in a recent answer, a resistor with 1 cubic centimeter volume will heat up about 1 degree centigrade per second, for each watt of power dissipated.

A resistor of 1/10th the size inn each dimension, or 1/1,000 the volume, will heat up 1,000X faster or 1,000 degree centigrade per second. Thus a 1mm^3 cube resistor will heat up at 1,000 degree C per watt per second.

However, with the thermal timeconstant of 1mm^3 of silicon being  0.0114 seconds ( down from the 11,400 seconds for a cubic meter of silicon, or 1 Milliion X slower ), the 1mm resistor heats up and starts to dump heat out the solder joint into the copper traces on the PCB. Should you be interested in further thermal modeling, standard copper foil (1 ounce/square foot, 35 microns thick, or 1.4 mils thick, 0.0014") has 70 degree  Centigrade per watt as the thermal resistance, for any size square of that foil.

Decades ago some newly minted techs asked me about overheating. We placed a 4.7 ohm resistor of rating 1/4 watt, across 5 volt supply.

** the resistor flared to fire in about 2 seconds. **

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience!